# Simple directive to work like a binding expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

what i am trying to do is create the following markup:

```
<current-user />
```

this directive should simply inject the current users username just like a binding expression {{currentUser.name}}

here is what i have but i am losing my span tag at the end for the `caret`:

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
  <current-user /> 
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive('currentUser', function ($rootScope, auth) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        compile: function (elem) {
            $rootScope.$watch('auth.profile', function (profile) {
                if (profile) {
                    elem.html(profile.email);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ahh.. `$rootScope.$watch` in `compile` of directive, why? & may I also know why `elem.html` as email would be simple text..

Comment: pretend i'm not using rootscope and the username could be anything. i just choose email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953#issuecomment-13135021) with some browsers.

Use a non-self closing directive to fix the problem.

```
  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <current-user></current-user>
    <span class="caret">Test</span>
  </a>
```

[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ft8MTQvjfqx5ISfXSr5P?p=preview)